# How can I output the raw text "<% foo %>" in ActionMailer + ERB template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, erb

We're implementing SendGrid unsubscribe groups ([documentation](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260806604209-Unsubscribe-Methods?source=search)). They require tags such as `<%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%>` to be included raw in the email that is then sent to SendGrid where they replace that tag.

How can I put these raw tags into my ERB template output with ActionMailer?

I've tried something like `<%= raw("<%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%>") %>` but it fails compilation. I've also tried escaping like `&lt;%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%&gt;` but then SendGrid doesn't replace it correctly.

Is there anyway for me to output this tag raw without escaping it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `<%%= asm_group_unsubscribe_url %>`?

Double percent symbol `<%%` indicates that you want the literal `<%`

Comment: That's good to know, exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately it seems like the output is still html encoded before it reaches SendGrid and they didn't replace it.